# jQuery execute jQuery event only after native event

Tags: jquery, event-handling, event-propagation

i have a function

```
<a href="somePage" class="dynamicLink" onclick="loadPage();">Some page</a>

$(document).on("click", ".dynamicLink", function(e) {
   alert("Load page has finish");
});
```

I want to trigger the alert only after loadPage function has finish executing. How do I do this?

Comment: move this alert to the end of `loadPage()` function.

Comment: The event is already being called after `loadPage()` as a result of bubbling

Comment: @megawac: Indeed, should be. You should make that an answer (with more explanation), so the OP can accept it.

Comment: @megawac, assuming of course that `loadPage` doesn't perform some sort of ajax call, in which case the alert should happen as part of the ajax callback.